# Why does a prop change not change data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand why changing a prop, used to provide an initial value, doesn't cause the data variable to change.

In the below example, changing the `initialName` value passed in the parent component, also causes the `initialName` to change in the child component. However, `name` keeps the value it was originally initialized as. I believed, seemingly incorrectly, that changing a prop would re-render the component.

---

`ChildComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{initialName}}
        {{name}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        initialName: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            name: this.initialName,
        };
    },
</script>
```

---

`ParentComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
    <ChildComponent :initialName="AnExampleName"/>
</template>
<script>
import ChildComponent from ChildComponent.vue
export default {
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    }
</script>
```

---

I've been able to work around this by watching the prop and updating `name`, however this doesn't feel like the best approach.

How come changing the prop doesn't change the data? Is there a better way to pass an initial value to a child component?

Comment: No reference is maintained when you set the data property value to a prop value inside of your data() method.  If you wanted to maintain that reference, you could do manual assignment ```this.name = this.initialName``` during one of the lifecycle hooks.  That said, I have to wonder why you want the prop change to update the data property and have 2 duplicate values?

Comment: @JamesAllen this is a minimal repro explaining the use case, the broader scope would probably make sense in the real app. And no, state set in `data()` is no longer reactive when your initialisation is done. You can check my playground example to have a proof of that. It's also somehow written in the documentation.

Comment: @JamesAllen The context is slightly simplified to highlight the problem I was facing/specifics of what was confusing me. (Might have accidentally over-simplified.) The parent component, in this case, passes a suggested value - the child component can choose to accept it, or overwrite it. Crucially, the suggested value can change after initialization. Out of curiosity, what lifecycle hook would you recommend using?

Comment: There are no hooks regarding a state update by itself, it's usually more of the life of the component itself. [updated](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated) is not really tackling the local state part of a component. `watch` would be useful but still, regular `this.variable = 'new value'` or a `computed` are totally fine regarding the reactivity system and work perfectly. In general, the most used hooks in Vue are `created()` for some API calls + `mounted()` for basic operations while having the DOM properly mounted. I may be wrong tho, feel free to correct me if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` is meant to be static, so if you set it once, it will not be reactive afterwards.
It will change if you mutate it directly of course, like this `this.name = 'updated value hi hi'`.
But it will **not mutate** if you update another prop/state elsewhere (like `initialName` in your example).

A simple approach for this would be to use a `computed` like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    initialName: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    name() {
      return this.initialName
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

---

[This example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8ZGl2PlxuICAgIDxidXR0b24gQGNsaWNrPVwiQW5FeGFtcGxlTmFtZSA9ICd5b2xvJ1wiPnVwZGF0ZSBpdDwvYnV0dG9uPlxuICAgIFxuICAgIDxici8+XG4gICAgPENoaWxkIDppbml0aWFsLW5hbWU9XCJBbkV4YW1wbGVOYW1lXCIgLz5cbiAgPC9kaXY+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0PlxuaW1wb3J0IENoaWxkIGZyb20gJy4vQ2hpbGQudnVlJ1xuICBcbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgY29tcG9uZW50czoge1xuICAgIENoaWxkXG4gIH0sXG4gIGRhdGEoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIHtcbiAgICAgIEFuRXhhbXBsZU5hbWU6ICd0ZXN0JyxcbiAgICB9XG4gIH0sXG59XG48L3NjcmlwdD5cbiIsImltcG9ydC1tYXAuanNvbiI6IntcbiAgXCJpbXBvcnRzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcInZ1ZVwiOiBcImh0dHBzOi8vc2ZjLnZ1ZWpzLm9yZy92dWUucnVudGltZS5lc20tYnJvd3Nlci5qc1wiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJDaGlsZC52dWUiOiI8dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxkaXY+XG4gICAgPGRpdj5pbml0aWFsIG5hbWU6IHt7IGluaXRpYWxOYW1lIH19PC9kaXY+XG4gICAgPGRpdj5sb2NhbCBkYXRhIG5hbWU6IHt7IG5hbWUgfX08L2Rpdj5cbiAgPC9kaXY+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0PlxuZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQge1xuICBwcm9wczoge1xuICAgIGluaXRpYWxOYW1lOiB7XG4gICAgICB0eXBlOiBTdHJpbmcsXG4gICAgICBkZWZhdWx0OiAnJyxcbiAgICB9LFxuICB9LFxuICBkYXRhKCkge1xuICAgIHJldHVybiB7XG4gICAgICBuYW1lOiB0aGlzLmluaXRpYWxOYW1lLFxuICAgIH1cbiAgfVxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG4ifQ==) proves that the usage of `data` is **NOT** updating the `name` value (`initialName` is totally reactive) if you do use it like the OP did. The [usage of `computed`](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) solves this issue tho.

Comment: There's really no need for using a computed property here, initialName is available in the template from the prop itself, and will react when changed in the parent.

Comment: @JamesAllen I've answered you in my edited answer.

Comment: You really didn't though...I never claimed the data property would be updated along with the prop.

Comment: @JamesAllen not sure what you're talking about so. But you're are probably missing the point of the OP. Because using a `computed` is useful to have a reactive `name` here. The rest is kinda out of subject and I never said nor wrote a computed for `initialName`.

Comment: Computing name that returns an unmodified initialName prop is entirely pointless.

Comment: @JamesAllen I read OP's sentence: `changing the initialName value passed in the parent component, also causes the initialName to change in the child component. However, name keeps the value it was originally initialized as`. So, to get the same use case as told, a mutation of `initialName` needs to done. In that case, a `computed()` is totally relevant since otherwise, only `initialName` would be reactive. I mean, I don't know, there's OP's question and my playground answer to you, not sure what is difficult to understand with those 2 combined, since it solves the faced problem.

Comment: I understand perfectly well.

Comment: @JamesAllen not sure what is wrong with my answer so.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned on Laracasts that you can use `provide` and `inject` instead.

In your parent component:

```js
import { provide, ref } from 'vue';

const name = ref('John Doe');

setTimeout(() => {
  name.value = 'Jane';
}, 2000);
```

And in your child component:

```js
import { inject } from vue;

let name = inject('name');
```

You don't need to add it in props and any changes to `name` will reflect in both your parent and your child.

This works from your parent down to all its children. (So it's not app-wide. For that, try Pinia / VueX.)

For more, here's Jeffrey's free lesson:
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-3-step-by-step/episodes/22

Comment: The above syntax assumes you're using the composition API.